# How to manage configuration from several class libraries in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, configuration, appsettings

I'm looking for a best practice for managing configuration on a project with multiple class libraries. I'm looking for maintainability and ease of implementation.

Let's assume a simple example: A console project with 2 class libraries. Each class library need their own configuration settings, and there are some settings that are common to several.

**Class Library 1**

- CL1Setting
- GlobalSetting

**Class Library 2**

- CL2Setting
- GlobalSetting

A **first approach** would be to create all the necessary settings on the main project:

- GlobalSetting
- CL1Setting
- CL2Setting

But this present several problems:

- It can get cluttered fast if there are lots of settings.
- It is not easy to maintain: How to know which settings are needed for each library?
- It can create naming conflicts. What if CL1Setting and CL2Setting would have the same name?

An **ideal solution** for me (although I'm afraid not possible) would be having custom library settings in separate files, or at least different sections. Something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="globalSetting" value="cl1Global"/>
  </appSettings>
  <appSettings file="CL1.config" >
    <add key="cl1setting" value="cl1setting1"/>
  </appSettings>
  <appSettings file="CL2.config">
    <add key="cl2setting" value="cl2setting2"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions?

### EDIT

As Ken Henderson suggests, config sections are another approach. However, although with their own advantages, they require coding, so I don't find it ideal though. (This will probably end up being the best option though)

### EDIT 2

joseph.ferris suggestion to look at Configuration Section Designer on CodePlex (csd.codeplex.com) was good. I found further problems, reported here (in case some is interested) http://csd.codeplex.com/discussions/278354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a custom [configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) instead of appSettings.  This is commonly used by 3rd party libraries (log4net is the first that comes to mind) to provide a way to configure their settings via your app/web config file.  Note that this also provides the basis for how MS creates their configuration sections.

I've successfully used this in several different projects including one that included the ability to add new implementations of algorithms to an analysis program.

Comment: Thanks! This is another approach I studied  but forgot to include in the answer (I'll edit it). It's good, but it requires code to be written, instead of just adding settings to a config file. I find it a bit cumbersome :)

Comment: rgargente - Look at Configuration Section Designer on CodePlex (http://csd.codeplex.com).  Visual design of configuration sections and simple access to the contents through a singleton implementation.  I use it all the time and will never code a configuration section by hand again.

Comment: I've trying it. Everything seems to be fine until runtime. This error is driving me crazy:            
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for FooConfigSection

Comment: Solved it. I'll edit the question again. Bug reported here: http://csd.codeplex.com/discussions/278354

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own naming convention to reduce the risk of appSettings naming collisions.  And/or create custom configuration sections.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Shared.Setting1" value="..."/>

    <add key="CL1.setting1" value="..."/>
    <add key="CL1.setting2" value="..."/>

    <add key="CL2.setting1" value="..."/>
    <add key="CL2.setting2" value="..."/>

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure an administrator would need to know which setting belongs to which library, but a naming convention helps promote a logical grouping - I would use prefixes that are meaningful to an administrator, rather than say a class library name - e.g. "Logging." for appSettings related to logging.

Comment: I saw you use dot as separator. Microsoft themselves uses colon as separator. As you can see in some of their Azure samples where they have the prefix `ida:`.

Comment: @Fred, I agree, it's worth being consistent, so colon is a good choice since Microsoft use it.  Microsoft aren't consistent themselves, though - e.g. MVC appSettings such as ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled don't have any prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses colon as a delimiter for namespace in some of their code.
Example their [Azure samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs). Here they use `ida:` as prefix.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
```

In Microsoft ASP.NET in the Web.config file you can see:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```